# sometimes, javascript is multithread?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, alert, confirm

I found sometimes, JavaScript has more than one thread, this really annoyed me. I checked the web, and I found that people always say it is just one thread, but I encounter more than one. you can just copy the code put into an html file, and run.
You will see what I meant. Why javascript has more than one thread with alert, confirm, prompt? thanks for reading.

Note: to test it, you should get your jQuery and replace it.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function pauseWithAlert(){
  fireAjax();
  alert("pause at one thread, I guess before this OK is clicked, no javascript should be executed since single thread, and the runner is with this thread in this function fpause");
}

function pauseWithConfirm(){
  fireAjax();
  if(confirm("the message has been triggered, while the 1st thread is paused with this confirmation request, but the message from another thread has been presented to you")){
    //something;
  }
}

function pauseWithDeadLoop(){
  alert("after you click OK, I will trigger the message, and then let the 1st thread get into dead loop, you will not be able to see the message");
  fireAjax();
  while(true);
}


function fireAjax(){
  var location = document.location.toString();
  $.ajax({type:'get',dataType:'html',url:location,success: ajaxSuccess, error: ajaxError});
}

var message = "have you clicked the OK in the 1st thread, this is a message from 2nd thread, isn't it?";
function ajaxSuccess(){
  document.getElementById('ajaxmessage').textContent = message;  
}

function ajaxError(){
  document.getElementById('ajaxmessage').textContent = message;  
}

function clearMessage(){
  document.getElementById('ajaxmessage').textContent = "";  
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
I know that it was said javascript is just one thread.
However, I found that sometimes, it is not just one thread.
<br/>Click <span onclick="pauseWithAlert();">here to pause with an alert</span> or
  <span onclick="pauseWithConfirm();">here to pause with a confirm</span>, 
and the runner stops there in the 1st thread, but you will see a message from 
another thread below, so not single thread????? No!!!
<br/>Click <span onclick="pauseWithDeadLoop();">here</span> to stop the 1st thread 
with a dead loop, you will not see a message from another thread below.
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<span id=ajaxmessage></span>
<br/>
<span onclick="clearMessage();">Clear the above message</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you add the example to jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Not sure how this example is related to several threads

Comment: Without looking at the code too thoroughly, it should be noted that the a in ajax stands for asynchronous; perhaps the asynchronous behavior is what's confusing you?

Comment: You should read on AJAX and its behavior, then everything will be consistent

Comment: I don't think you can have multiple threads in JavaScript. They are all executed in a line.

Comment: I think a lot of commenters are actually misunderstanding the OP's point. He is not confused by asynchronous callbacks. Rather, he is confused at code being executed while an alert dialog is displayed, whereas presumably `alert` is a blocking call. I agree that this is confusing, and would be interested in an answer from someone very knowledgable about any popular JS implementations.

Comment: @DanTao yeah, you're sort of right. In pauseWithAlert and pauseWithConfirm he's calling fireAjax() first though, which is why the message shows. The third function locks before the readyState in the asynchronous call to XMLHttpRequest changes.

Comment: @Nathan: Calling `fireAjax` first still shouldn't cause the callback to fire before the alert is dismissed, though, at least in theory, according to most devs' understanding of JavaScript. The callback passed to `$.ajax` shouldn't even have a *chance* to execute until one more run through the event loop, at which point the alert should have been dismissed. So I at least understand the OP's confusion. I do have a couple possible explanations that don't involve multiple threads, though.

Comment: @DanTao `alert()` won't block the callback for the same reason that `setTimeout()` won't block the callback. Most modern Javascript engines event listeners will still fire the event, because they are not busy waiting (nor should they be).

Answer (score 7):

Javascript has only one working thread, but it has callbacks, so it might seems to you like there are multiple thread, but there are none.

Comment: Wow that upvote was fast! I actually just hit the submit button and saw 1, People here are fast! thanks...

Comment: Sometimes the `k` in `26.6` has some effect on this.

Comment: @zerkms. Didn't they tell you? _High rep stops working after 50K_ `:)`

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that this depends on the browser. But it doesn't actually demonstrate multiple threads.

Using the latest version of Chrome, for example, I don't see the behavior you're describing.

I *do* see something strange using the latest version of Firefox. Namely, the DOM appears to update (i.e., the callback passed to the AJAX request was fired) *while* (or *before*) the alert is displayed. I sense that you have concluded there must be multiple threads, then, since `alert` is supposed to be a blocking call.

I don't know this for a fact, but I have one theory as to why this might be the case. If you think about the semantics of `alert`, it requires that code *after* `alert` is called does not execute until the user has clicked "OK" (or whatever). But this doesn't actually mean that the call must block in the traditional sense (i.e., spin and wait). A JavaScript engine might actually implement `alert` as a callback-based protocol such that the code after the `alert` call constitutes a callback that is fired after the user clicks "OK."

According to this implementation, calling `$.ajax` followed by `alert` would be just like making two `$.ajax` calls in a row, in which case it would not be at all surprising that the first callback might fire before the second AJAX request has received a response.

Another possibility (haven't tested) is that Firefox simply has an optimization wherein AJAX requests to the current window location synchronously return the HTML of the current page. Far-fetched, perhaps, but certainly possible.

The main point I'm trying to make here is that you haven't actually uncovered proof of multiple threads in JavaScript. There are alternate explanations. However, I do share your confusion over what I agree is some puzzling behavior in at least one popular browser.

Comment: `alert()` won't block the call because you made the AJAX call prior to calling `alert()`. The reason why a busy loop blocks the call is because there is no processor time to check for the `onreadystatechange` event in the XMLHttpRequest. If you were to switch your XMLHttpRequests over to use synchronous calls instead, the 3rd function would also show a message.